# Creating libraries of non-Sobject test data

Tags: unit-test

I seem to end up writing more than my share of inboundEmailHandlers to process integration data that we otherwise can't get through a REST or SOAP interface.  For example:

- Parsing HTML emails modeled as `<table>`s into SObject fields
- Parsing CSV attachments on inbound emails into SObject fields

While writing the parsers is straightforward, if tedious, managing the test data leaves me searching for a better solution.

**Option 1 - Test Data factories in the testmethods**

- PRO: isolates the testmethod from the org data
- CON: Requires writing the factory which can be complex, especially for all the variants of data; and a real nightmare for HTML emails

**Option 2 - Brute force test data factories** - long string fields that contain the inbound CSV or HTML - saved in Lists

Example:

```
List<String> csvTestCases = new List<String> {
      'testcase0Row0,def,ghi, ........' + '\n' + 'testCase0Row1,jkl,mno, ...' + ... ,
      'testcase0Row1,def,ghi, ........' + '\n' + 'testCase1Row1,jkl,mno, ...' + ... ,
      ... 
 }
```

- PRO: Isolates testdata from org
- PRO: No factory code to write
- PRO: Can be used to adapt live datasets into test data (albeit with some editing)
- CON: Lots of cut and paste to create, always missing a quote or too many quotes as you can't have strings that cross line breaks. Really hard to maintain.

**Option 3 - Static Resources**

- Use power editors to create the test data (Excel, HTML editor, ..)
- Copy paste the resulting files into static resources
- Testmethod factories then read from StaticResource using SOQL, converting from base64 into string.

  ```
    for (StaticResource sr: [select id, body from StaticResource where name like 'Test%']) {
       // convert base64 data into string and inject into test
    }
  ```
- PRO: Creating test data is easy; can leverage live data to build up example testsets
- PRO: Factory code is simple
- PRO: Isolates testdata from org; staticResources can be migrated from environments. Note that the Apex Developers Guide does not state that `StaticResource` is available when using @isTest but I think the doc is wrong as this testmethod passes the assert:

  ```
   @isTest
      private static void testFoo() {
          system.assert([select count() from staticResource] > 0);
      }
  ```

**So - am I missing something better?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely think that option 3 is your best best in this case, there was a reasonably recent change to the platform that actually promotes the use of storing test data in static resources because it's a common use case: [check out the documentation here.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_load_data.htm) I'm sure you've read that already and know it's about storing SOBject data hence your question.

I believe your test is valid and that static resources should be available in tests as they're not stored the same way as regular data; that said, if you have issues you could perhaps store a CSV for an SObject and simply use a rich text area field to store the html content.

Comment: thanks LaceySnr - and yep, I knew about the doc ref above - great for sobjects; not for non-sobjects.  I recently switched to option3 for HTML emails and it works well - I probably saved dozens of edit-compile loops from options 1 and 2 (which i have used in the past). I'll hold this answer open for a bit to see if someone else has a super clever idea I haven't thought of. As for the doc error, I've sent in the necessary feedback form.

Comment: Yeah I'm interested in finding out if there's anything better. The only other thing I can think of (not very clean) is to use VF pages to store the HTML, then grab the body of the page in apex.